# How to use SVG icon as a prop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in Lucide icons, we can import for example `Loader` and `Loader2` icons and pass them as a prop to our component. Let's assume that I have two svg icons and I'd like to use them in a similar way as a prop to my custom React component and call it as below. How can I do that?

```
interface ButtonProps {
    icon: WhatToPutHere?
}

export const Button = ({icon}: ButtonProps) => {
    return <button><icon className="icon"/></button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can type it as `LucideIcon`.

```
import type { LucideIcon } from 'lucide-react';
interface ButtonProps {
    icon: LucideIcon
}

export const Button = ({ icon : Icon }: ButtonProps) => <button><Icon /></button>;
```

Then, it can be used like this:

```
import { Loader } from 'lucide-react';

<Button icon={Loader} />; // for example
```